# flash as3 displays play button with a "cut out"...please help!

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I just created a Play button and flash displays it in a very weird manner...I used different triangles with different formats and resolutions, it is always the same:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why there is this "edge" in the play button? 
The "edge" is not visible in the Flash SDK but I'm seeing it in the browser.
The image for the play button is ok - there is no edge in the pic.

Comment: Are you scaling the image at all? I believe that may cause you an issue, especially if you have smoothing disabled.

Comment: i'm not scaling at all ... that's the strange thing ... but i will check on the smoothing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling or an offset of the images x or y from a full pixel could be causing the problem. ( be sure to check all parent DisplayObjects too! ) Also try turning smoothing on to see if it makes a difference.